# Can I bypass this http login form and get to the index page without the username and password?

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, forms

I have a router and I need to get to the configuration page without username and password because i have lost them and they are not the default ones... I don't wanna reset the router. The login form is HTTP form which is shown insecure by google Chrome. I inspected the element and I could see that the username and password were being combined in one variable and then being encoded to base64 like this :-

```
var string=username+":"+passwd;
 document.passWarning.LoginPassword.value="";
   var passd=encodeBase64( string);
   document.passWarning.action="/cgi-bin/index.asp?"+passd;
   //alert(document.passWarning.action);
  document.passWarning.submit();
```

here, username and passwd are the data from form &
name of form is passWarning and method is post.

Can i access the index.asp page by changing something in the form?
WHERE IS THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD BEING CHECKED IF ITS RIGHT OR WRONG?

Comment: SO is not hacking site. Please do the reset.

Comment: Yes you can if you are too good to hack it. else NO

Comment: have you tried looking up the documentation for the router in question to see if the username and password are the factory defaults?

Comment: i just wanna now if its possible to get to the index page... Because it asks for the base64 formatted username and password in the URL...

Comment: THEY ARE NOT DEFAULT...THEY WERE CHANGED

Comment: CAN ANYONE SAY WHERE IS THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD BEING CHECKED IF ITS RIGHT OR WRONG?

Comment: what's with all the screaming?

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: your credentials are checked in the backend, not in your browser. If you have lost them, you have to reset the router.

Comment: Why on Earth did you tag this with PHP, Javascript, etc???

Comment: ohh sorry...Javascript is there but no PHP...sorry

Comment: welcome to the internet, typing in all caps is considerer SHOUTING(SCREAMING)

Comment: ohh sorry then... i wasnt shouting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to reset the router.

The only way you could look at the password was if you had backed up the router's configuration in a text file.

What's in the router anyway that you are so fearful of resetting it?

Wouldn't start World War III now would it? ;)

Comment: ok fine i would reset but how is the router checking if i have entered the wrong password?!?!?!

Comment: That logic is written in index.asp ASP is Active Server Pages which is backend of router page. As I said, you would need to have access to the router config file or whatever place the router stores the admin password to get to know the password.

Comment: and is there no way to have access to the place where the router stores the password

Comment: Most router don't store the user ID or password where it could be read back. They use one-way encryption, and it's part of the OS on the router.

Comment: Nope, just reset it and be done with it.